Whether to have tags for specific software and tools?
Following on from the question: Are questions about coding psychology and cognitive science experiments, simulations, etc. on topic?
I was wondering whether we should have specific tags for particular tools, software, etc.
A few candidate tags:R, Matlab, Inquisit, Eprime, Python, 

I don't see any problem with them.

I don't think we should have programming language specific tags. Questions should be about cognitive science, which should be independent of particular programming language. If you need to ask "How do I do this?" then the question might be fine, but if you are asking "How do I do this in Matlab?" then CogSci might not be the place to ask.

I'm torn, I partially agree with Aarth and partially with Artem. Inquisit and Eprime should definitely be worth a tag here, but I'm not sure how Python would be particularly relevant. R and Matlab are closer, but I'm on the fence about that as well. Math and statistical stuff should probably be on topic, but getting into particulars like using complex software might be better off on other sites, even if it's not explicitly off-topic.

This should be fine. Cross Validated has tags for SPSS, STATA, even MINITAB. This would be in keeping with other sites.
